# Shortcut key for commit and push in PhpStorm 2017 - Windows

Tags: windows, phpstorm, shortcut, phpstorm-2017.1

What I do now in PhpStorm is press:

1. `Ctrl + K`  to commit
2. `Ctrl + Enter` to confirm the Commit dialog
3. `Ctrl + Shift + K` to push
4. `Ctrl + Enter` to confirm the Push dialog

What I want to accomplish is after I completed the commit massage, PhpStorm will automatically push without prompting me again to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You can [record a macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/recording-macros.html) and assign a shortcut to it.

Comment: no.It is not a good solution. It will try to push before the commit even submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> as stated in the PhpStorm docs: [Commit and push changes to Git repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/commit-and-push-changes.html).

This automatically does your steps 2 and 3. If you want to also remove step 4, you have to uncheck the "For Commit and Push to non-protected branches, preview commits before push" checkbox:

[image: "For Commit and Push to non-protected branches, preview commits before push" checkbox in the PhpStorm Git push dialog]

In some cases, Push dialog might not have that checkbox. So the only choice is to to manually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> then.